BackOff error when deploying repo to Azure Kubernetes
I have a repo that I cant push to Azure Kubernetes. My repo is working pretty well when built and run at local Docker. However, everytime I try to deploy it to Azure Kubernetes, I get some kind of BackOff Error.
Warning  BackOff    2s (x3 over 16s)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container hemsida in pod hemsida-86899747f4-ft5wh_default(5aad38cd-f2e6-45cf-8678-bcb2d6901b4d)

Its just a Flask app saying 'Hello World', so nothing complicated that requires enviroment variables.
This is my deployment.yaml that I use,
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hemsida
  labels:
    app: hemsida
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hemsida
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hemsida
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hemsida
        image: hemsidatest.azurecr.io/hemsida:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1200
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: acr-secret


This is basically my code,
from quart import Quart

app = Quart(__name__)

@app.route('/')
async def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=1200)


Why am I getting this BackOff error? I have tried three days with ChatGPT and deploying the app multiple times. I still get some ImagePullBackOff.
I tried to push my code to ACR, e.g. making acr-secret, pushing the code, and still it gets an error reading from the image.
I tried to push the code to my Docker Hub, and transfering the files through a Docker Hub connection, but still not successfull.

hemsidatest.azurecr.io doesn't seem to exist.

Yes, it should not, I removed the cluster.

The ImagePullBackOff error occurs when a container within a pod fails to pull the required image from a container registry. This error can occur due to incorrect image names or tags, missing credentials.
When a pod is created, Kubernetes tries to pull the container image specified in the pod's definition from the container registry. If the image cannot be pulled, Kubernetes sets the pod's status to ImagePullBackOff, indicating that it will no longer attempt to pull the image until the underlying issue is resolved.
For more details about the ImagePullBackOff error, refer to this link and SO.
I used this link to configure Kubernetes using Python.
deployment.yaml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-python-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: hello-python
  ports:
  - protocol: "TCP"
    port: 6000
    targetPort: 5000
  type: LoadBalancer


---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-python
spec:
  replicas: 4
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-python
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello-python
        image: hello-python:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000


Dockerfile
FROM 3.8-slim

RUN  mkdir  /app

WORKDIR  /app

ADD  .  /app/

RUN  pip  install  -r  requirements.txt

EXPOSE  5000

CMD  ["python",  "/app/main.py"]






I used this SO to push Python code and connect my pod on Azure Kubernetes Service.



